# better to rewrite my RoR website or find another webhost? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, web-hosting

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and spent the past week writing my first website. I am in the process of deploying it from my localserver to production but I realized that my webhost only has Rails **version 2.3.14 or 2.3.17** installed.
 I'm using the webhost's cpanel to install the Rails version to make the process easier. 
I used Rails 3.2.3 to write my entire website. Any recommendation on what is the best solution? 
Should I make all of the adjustments to a Rails 2.x version? Or should I look for a new webhost? or some other option?

Comment: IMO, I think you should keep up-to-date on the latest-ish version of Rails (seeing as Rails 4 is brewing somewhere..)

Comment: Looks like it's time to find a new web host.

Comment: I'd go with a new webhost, too. Even Rails 3 came out 2 1/2 years ago. And Rails 4 released its beta1 a few days ago.

Comment: I agree with @JavaNut13, find a new host, if you plan on doing a lot of Rails, Python or Node.js development i would suggest getting a cheap VPS, or using something like Heroku.

Comment: Is it still possible to get my RoR website working on this webhost if I don't go through their cpanel? Do it more manually? I'm trying to cut my costs since I've paid them already and a refund is not possible.

Comment: That depends entirely on the webhost. Maybe you could tell us what plan and what host you use?

Comment: I'm using Stablehost (http://www.stablehost.com/shared-hosting.php) and I'm signed up for the yearly BASIC plan.

Comment: Or if it's a simpler application, you can deploy it to heroku with really good performance for exactly 0 money.

Answer (score 2):

New webhost.  I recommend checking out Heroku - especially for new/small projects, where you can get your feet wet for free.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3

See also https://github.com/fastestforward/heroku_san

Comment: I agree with kwerle. Heroku is a great cloud application, hassle free that supports Rails(I think it's actually build in Rails as well).

Comment: I'm going to try Heroku as my first option. Any good tutorial to deploy for a true beginner?

Comment: Check out both the links I supplied.  The first is Heroku's walk through.  The second one is a gem that makes beginning easy.

Comment: And here is a new Code School segment on deploying there:
http://www.codeschool.com/code_tv/heroku

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me when using bluehost.com.

I considered using Heroku.com to deploy, but then I found this wonderful tutorial by Ryan Bates on how to deploy my app to a VPS: http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps

You don't have all the advantages of a cPanel, but it gives you total control of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a VPS is well worrh it and on the plus side you will learn a thing or two about basic linux administration.